# First .slice() and then do things with all other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, slice

I was quite sure that I already did this in some earlier version of jQuery, but http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ seems to suggest otherwise.

What I'm looking for is similar kind of the opposite of `.addBack()` - a traversing function that uses "all other" elements (not `.not()`!)

Preusdo Example:

```
$('.some-class li').slice(33,55).hide().allOthers().show()
```

*Edit: This is not actually a hide() / show() based problem, this is just a simple example to clarify what I meant.*

First, I'ld like to manipulate a set of elements selected with `.slice()`, and then manipulate all elements that were **not** selected by `.slice()`.

**Is there a handy traversing function I've missed that does just that?** I know how to solve it in general, but a `".allOthers()"` method that I might have missed would certainly be more handy and clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can just call show before calling slice

```
$('.some-class li').show().slice(33,55).hide();
```

It's true that there is no method to get all others, the closest is to get back they previous collection as you mentioned, http://api.jquery.com/addback/

You could implement a plugin, since I'm on my mobile, I'll just write some straight code

```
// o(n*m), could be improved
function allOthers(jqObj) {
   var current = [].concat(jqObj);
   var prev = jqObj.addBack();

   return prev.filter(function(obj){
      return !current.includes(obj);
   });

}
```

Comment: @gurvinder372 I just realized how bad my example was, there - since the show() / hide() was just meant to clarify, it's not the actual problem I'm facing (where I have to separate the elements, unlike in this case). But you answered my question basically by saying tha there is no method that does the required functionality.

Comment: It could be implemented as a plugin, I'm trying it from my phone

Comment: Could you add a ");" at the end of return? It's missing, and I can't edit it since it wants more than 6 characters changed per edit ;)

Answer (score 1):

First show all of them and then hide from 33 to 55, here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/nefvL0c3/)

```
$('.some-class li').show().slice(33,55).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

After testing @JuanMendes suggestion, I played around with it a bit and found quite a compact way to implement this kind of functionality, due to jQuery's prevObject:

```
$.fn.others = function() {
  return this.prevObject.not( this );
}
```

I didn't test it too much with other methods, so it might needs some further changes - but it seems to work fine with `.slice()` at least.

https://jsfiddle.net/1L3db7k4/

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, looks better than mine ;) If you don't, I'll copy your solution to my answer, since that will bubble up to the top.

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks! Well, I can't accept my own answer until in 2 days anyways ;) For now I'll leave yours, I'll change it in 2 days. But yeah, it's a bit unlucky that I found my own answer, haha.

Comment: That's the best way, my first question at SO was also answered by me.